# Dwarf Fortress Traps and Levers

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I know if/which trap/door/etc is linked to which lever?

Comment: Can't dfhack do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Label them with a [note](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/DF2012:Note) <kbd>N</kbd> when constructed.

Comment: Depends on what version you're using. Maybe it's time for me to upgrade.

Comment: @INever maybe it __is__ time for you to upgrade.

Answer (score 11):

You don't.

It's practically impossible to see what a lever operates without pulling it and seeing what happens.

You basically have a few options:

1. Place the lever near the thing it affects (not great if you're wanting to consolidate levers to one control room with a stressed-out, twitchy dwarf).
2. Color-code the levers by making them out of [materials that have known colors](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:The_Non-Dwarf%27s_Guide_to_Rock).
3. Color-code the wall behind or floor around a lever with a specific colored rock.
4. Use specific colored rock to create a floor mosaic with letter(s) to label the lever.
5. Organize your levers into bays (one alcove has door levers, another has traps).
6. Any combination of the above.

Comment: lame. and welcome to the site @I Never!

Comment: or label them with a note. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/dwarf-fortress-traps-and-levers/2250#2250

Answer (score 8):

Levers can't be linked to the same door/trap twice. If you have patience, you can try to link the lever to a new trap, browse through the whole list of traps and see which one is missing.